# Where are asp.net website project settings stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

If we look at the settings page of a asp.net website project ( press alt+enter ) . It looks like this:

[image]

However, no where in the solution / website folder i can find out where these settings are stored ? there is no csproj file created for "website project" .

The reason I am asking this is because when I  add the solution to github , and then clone on another machine, the references are lost and the project will not compile anymore. But if i copy the entire project folder to another computer, it compiles fine.
So for sure, there are some settings file that are not added to git repo.

Does anyone have any idea where these settings are stored ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but aren't those stored in the .csproj file?

Comment: there is no .csproj file generated for web project. That is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write down what I found later on for anyone's reference. The Contents in the reference list ( as pasted in the image above ) seem to be read real time from Bin folder of the project . So adding a dll file in Bin folder directly and closing/opening the Property page will show the newly added Bin file as reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .sln file for website projects, just not where you might expect it. For Web Site projects, it is created in your default Projects location e.g. `C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YourWebSite\YourWebSite.sln` (or wherever you have your default Projects location set up in Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions).

Comment: Actually the solution was already inside the web folder ( had created a solution first and then added web site project to it ) . However, the solution does not contain the reference to BIN files.